# How do I query for distinct values in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have a problem where I want to be able to get all the unique cities for a collection, and my code looks something like this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    born_in_city: String
});
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

In native MongoDb I could just do `db.person.distinct("born_in_city")`, but there doesn't seem to be anything equivalent for Mongoose. Is the only option to iterate over all of the documents myself to do this, or is there a better solution?

In an attempt to use the underlying `node-mongodb-native` as suggested by the answerer I attempted to do this:

```
mongoose.connection.db.collections(function(err, collections){
  collections[0].distinct('born_in_city', function( err, results ){
    console.log( err, results );
  });
});
```

However the `results` is empty and there's no error. I would also prefer to be able to fetch only the needed collection by name rather than have to filter what `collections` return if at all possible.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Just to give an update for Mongoose 3.x:

```
MyModel.find().distinct('_id', function(error, ids) {
    // ids is an array of all ObjectIds
});
```

Comment: You can also call it directly on the [Model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-distinct).  `MyModel.distinct('_id', { foo: 'bar' }, function(error, ids)...`

Comment: How can I then order the result by ids ?

Comment: From the example in the Mongoose Docs (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort), I would think that you could write: `MyModel.find({ sort: { '_id': -1 }}).distinct('_id', function(error, ids){/* handle result */});`

Comment: @Risadinha: It is showing: " sort cannot be used with distinct "

Comment: To then sort the resulting array of ids, simply use javascript Array.prototype.sort() : `MyModel.distinct('_id', function(error, ids) { ids.sort(); ... })`

Comment: The callback function is also optional here if you just want to return that list of unique _ids without venturing into callback hell.

Comment: how can i use limit with this? it throws error

Answer (score 24):

In my program, this code works.

```
Person.collection.distinct("born_in_city", function(error, results){
  console.log(results);
});
```

by 
node.js v0.4.7, 
mongoose 1.3.3

Comment: i want to use limit too. but this does not allow

Answer (score 3):

```js
const findBornCity = async() => {
    const bornCity = await Person.find().distinct("born_in_city")
    return bornCity
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I read through the source code and the node-mongodb-native driver is what powers the class.  So on the connection object. So after you have done mongoose.connect(mongodb://), you can give this a shot.

```
if(mongoose.connections.length > 0) {
  var nativeconn = mongoose.connections[0].conn;
  nativeconn.person.distinct('born_in_city', function(error, results){

  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `mongoose.connections[0].conn` is undefined for me, however I'm pretty sure `mongoose.connection` returns the same thing for the active connection. Though I can't use `mongoose.connection.person` like you suggested, instead I made a call to `mongoose.connection.db.collections( .. )`, but once I ran `collection.distinct( .. )` the results were empty. I updated my question to reflect my attempts so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.distinct("field")
   .exec()
   .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
   });
```

https://www.cltechhome.com/2023/02/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in.html