# mongoose: find unique categories to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

below are an example of "documents", representing shop products in a mongodb. I am wondering what would be the most efficient way of retrieving the categories as an array from a node api? for example i want a result of ["womens clothing", "mens clothing"]. I really do not want to loop through all the records in the db, or is there a way i can query the category property directly.

```
 [{
            "name":"eu sit voluptate",
            "description":"Deserunt magna minim in nisi ad nisi amet. Cillum in aliquip ex fugiat ut nisi Lorem amet laboris magna occaecat tempor. Nostrud quis nisi minim aute consectetur quis consectetur in nulla. Laboris velit sunt et adipisicing duis consequat do.\r\n",
            "color":"neutral",
            "price":751.12,
            "category":"womens clothing",
            "subcategory":"tops",
            "id":1,
            "sizes":"XL",
            "images":[
               "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=320%C3%97320&w=320&h=320"
            ],
            "brand":"paul_smith",
            "created":"2015-01-01T12:53:31 -00:00",
            "inStock":true,
            "sale":[
               {
                  "onSale":false,
                  "salePercOff":10
               }
            ]
         },{
            "name":"sit proident mollit",
            "description":"Occaecat proident adipisicing cillum Lorem in. Nulla ipsum culpa eu proident pariatur culpa. Eiusmod consequat qui ex deserunt sunt ut ullamco labore minim proident sint ipsum officia.\r\n",
            "color":"neutral",
            "price":626.6,
            "category":"mens clothing",
            "subcategory":"jumpers",
            "id":15,
            "sizes":40,
            "images":[
               "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=320%C3%97320&w=320&h=320"
            ],
            "brand":"james_reed",
            "created":"2014-12-18T03:50:19 -00:00",
            "inStock":true,
            "sale":[
               {
                  "onSale":true,
                  "salePercOff":10
               }
            ]
         }]
```

Comment: i think I've found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043847/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Answer is a simple query:

```
db.shop.distinct('category');
```