# Chaining collection methods / promises in get request Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get some data from a MongoDB database with the find() method, returning only those documents that contain a specified "room". Then, I want to return all distinct values, of the found array of rooms, whose key is equal to "variety". I tried this in two different ways and I could be way off in my approach. The first way was to chain the collection methods find() and distinct(). This did not work:

**This is what the plantList collection looks like:**

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56c11a761b0e60030043cbae"
    },
    "date added": "10/21/2016",
    "variety": "Lettuce",
    "room": "Room 1"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56c11a761b0e60030043cbaf"
    },
    "date added": "10/21/2015",
    "variety": "Tomatoes",
    "room": "Room 2"
}
]
```

**server.js**

```
//plantList = db collection
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI, function(err, db) {
var plantList = db.collection("plantList");

app.get('/gettypesbyroom/:room', function(req, res) {
       var roomReq = req.params.room;
        plantList
        .find({"room":roomReq})
            .toArray()
                .distinct("variety", function(err, docs) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.json(docs);
                });
});
});
```

My second approach was to chain promises with .then() and use underscore.js to select the keys of the array of rooms (also did not work):

```
app.get('/gettypesbyroom/:room', function(req, res) {
       var roomReq = req.params.room;
        plantList
        .find({"room":roomReq})
            .toArray(function(err, docs) {
                if (err) throw err;
                return docs;
            }).then(function(docs) {
            _.keys(docs, function(docs) { return docs.variety; });
        }).then(function(varieties) {
            res.json(varieties); //not inside scope of .get function?
        });
});
```

Is there something I could do differently to make these work or perhaps a different approach altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling it without `toArray`:

```
//plantList = db collection
app.get('/gettypesbyroom/:room', function(req, res) {
  var roomReq = req.params.room;

  plantList
  .find({ room: roomReq })
  .distinct('type', function(err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

See [How Do I Query For Distinct Values in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043847/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose).

Comment: @muninn9, what does the error say, and what is the stack trace?

Comment: I'm running it on Postman, it just says "500 Internal Service Error"

Comment: @muninn9 I would suggest trying to find the Postman logs. Other than that, can you provide your schema for `plantList`? Is that a model?

Comment: I'm not using a schema, I'm using mongojs. I modified the code above to show plantList.

Comment: @muninn9 Which model is inside of `plantList`? You should be using `<Model>.find().distinct()`

Comment: I never created a model. All of my other queries have worked without it. Perhaps this is where the problem is?

Comment: @muninn9 Perhaps. As I said, the method is `<Model>.find().distinct()`

Comment: I switched over from the native driver to Mongoose and it now works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two more ways. One is to make it easier with a projection operator - just project what you need. Eg. if you have a document that looks like:

```
{
  room: 123,
  type: 'soundproof_room',
  other: 'stuff'
}
```

...you can project it with a query like this to just select the `type`:

```
db.rooms.find({ room: room }, { type: 1 }).toArray();
```

That would give you an array of objects like this:

```
let roomTypes = [{type: 'soundproof_room'}, {type: 'windy_room'}, {type: 'soundproof_room'}, {type: 'room without doors'}]
```

(Obviously, I'm making `types` up, I don't know what they really are.)

And then use a simple map:

```
return res.json(
  roomTypes
    // extract the type
    .map(room => room.type)  
    // filter out duplicates
    .filter((type, idx, self) => self.indexOf(type) === idx)
);
```

(I'm using ES6 arrow fn, hope you can read it, if not: babeljs.io/repl/)

Another thing to try is an aggregation.

```
db.rooms.aggregate({
  // first find your room
  $match: { room: room }
},
{
  // group by type, basically make distinct types
  $group: {
    _id: '$type',
    count: {$sum: 1} // inc this by 1 for each room of this type
  }
});
```

That one would get you your room, and it would return you only the types of rooms and the count per type, as an added bonus.

Comment: But of course, this may not be what you need - now from comments on the other answer, I get the feeling I didn't understand exactly what you need? Just the distinct room types for your rooms?

Comment: I apologize for not making this more clear. The answer has been updated to more clearly reflect the document. Each document would look like {room: 'Room 2', variety: 'Lettuce', date added: '10/21/2016', etc.}

Comment: But you're doing a `distinct`. Also, you're filtering by room. So all rooms would be `'Room 2'` in that case, and you'd get only one out of each variety, even if the db has more of them?