# only return document _id on mongoose .find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I update 100's of documents every second by pushing new data to an array in its document. To get the document of which I am going to add data to, I use the mongoose `.find().limit(1)` function, and return the whole document. It works fine.

To help with some memory and cpu issues I have, I was wondering how I could get `find()` to only return the `id` of the document so I can use that to $push or $set new data.

Thanks.

Comment: The second parameter of `find` function is a string, specifies which document fields to include or exclude. To include only `_id` use `collection.find({}, '_id')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [Projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection) to tell your query exactly what you want off of your objects.

`_id` is always included unless you tell it not to.

```
readings = await collection
.find({
    name: "Some name you want"
})
.project({
    _id: 1 // By default
})
.toArray();
```

Comment: `collection.find({}, '_id')` is not enough?

Comment: @alexmac I think that works too (although the second parameter may need to be an object), but I like the `.project()` since it is more explicit.

Comment: Would there be any way to return the id and the length (only the length) of a array in the document? Or would i be better off returning the whole document in that case?

Comment: @Manu length of what? An array property on an individual document?  I'm not sure.

Comment: @alexmac do you know if there is a performance difference between either form?

Comment: `Aggregate#project` appends a new `$project` operator to the aggregate pipeline. So it's for aggregation, when the second parameter in `find` function known as _projection_ includes or excludes fields in regular select operation.

Comment: I meant for example if my document has an array in it. The only value I need from that document is the length of that array. Would it be possible to only return that value and the _id of the doco?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `distinct` method in order to get an array of `_id` for your query.

Follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043847/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @alexmac, this works for me:

```
collection.find({}, '_id')
```