# How to extract only one value from mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

LIKE I HAVE THREE FIELD 'TO','FROM' AND 'MESSAGE', I just want to display content of message field where I have given some clause in to and from.
Document{{_id=59c7d57c674cd5673c304936, to=9915103230, from=9915103229, date=24/12/2017, message=HELLO WORLD}}

I JUST WANT TO RETRIEVE "HELLO WORLD", not the whole document.

Like I just want, String message=?????---> I need some method here so the Variable of String type gets the value Hello World.

Projection method is not working for me.

I am using JDBC MongoDB 3.5 Driver.

Comment: we can't help you when the question is a mess, there's no input/output and no signs of effort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [only return document \_id on mongoose .find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284659/only-return-document-id-on-mongoose-find).  You use [Projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection).  I explain a little about how to use it in my answer.

Comment: @zero298 I did your implementation but it didn't work or maybe I had it implemented wrongly because I am new to mongoDB, I was getting error at "await"-I don't remember the exact error message though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a functioning prog.  Compile against the 3.5 drivers.

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase( "testX" );
        MongoCollection<BsonDocument> coll = db.getCollection("foo", BsonDocument.class);
        coll.drop();

        {
            BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument();
            doc.put("from", new BsonInt32(23343223));
            doc.put("to", new BsonInt32(23343223));
            doc.put("msg", new BsonString("hello"));
            coll.insertOne(doc);

            doc.remove("_id");
            doc.put("from", new BsonInt32(8889));
            doc.put("to", new BsonInt32(99999));
            doc.put("msg", new BsonString("goodbye"));
            coll.insertOne(doc);
        }

        {
            BsonDocument query = new BsonDocument("from", new BsonInt32(8889));
            BsonDocument proj = new BsonDocument("msg", new BsonInt32(1));
            proj.put("_id",new BsonInt32(0));

            BsonDocument d2 = coll.find(query).projection(proj).first();
            System.out.println(d2);

            String s2 = coll.find(query).projection(proj).first().getString("msg").getValue();
            System.out.println(s2);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use projection, the second optional argument to find().  For context, this gives you the whole document:

db.yourCollection.find({to:9915103230,from:9915103229});

This gives you only message from the results.   Just name the field and set it to 1:

db.yourCollection.find({to:9915103230,from:9915103229},{message:1};

You can specify more than one thing to return:

db.yourCollection.find({to:9915103230,from:9915103229},{message:1, to:1};

Comment: also, you can suppress the `_id` field by passing `_id:0`

Comment: Please see my Question again. I tried your thing but its not working. Thanks.

Comment: @Ratik Look at my second post here.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Ya, I did saw and its working. Thanks

Comment: @Ratik Good!  Don't be shy about voting it up to help others.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I did vote it up but it wasn't reflected in public voting, as I am new user with less reputation score<15.