# 2018 MongoDB distinct count for NodeJS Express Mongoose API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I am trying to get this value (db.collecName.distinct('fieldName').length) basically a count of distinct docs, but in a ReactJS-Express-Mongoose API route.

Should be in this format of API call :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    ModelName.find(function (err, CollecName){
      if(err) return next(err);
      res.json(CollecName);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't get it. If you're trying to get `db.collecName.distinct('fieldName')` then why don't you use that in your code?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to code it properly so I thought I would ask for ideas for the structure.

Comment: Well, you got it. You gave the answer in the question. You have the code, you just didn't try it for some reason. Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043847/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, Those pieces of code were enough to help me write what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jeremy T.,

```
router.get('/count', function(req, res, next){
    ModelName.find().distinct('fieldName', function(err, Response) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        // console.log(Response.length);
        res.json(Response.length);
    });
});
```

~ SOLUTION