# Mongoose and Express, How can I get unique records from db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my database, I have 2-3 records with `title` (Article one).
How can I get only 1 result?

Following is my code that doesn't work,

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Article.find.distinct(title, (err, title) => {    
  if(err){
  console.log(err);
} else {
  console.log(articles);
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Articles',
    articles: title
    });
   }
  });
});
```

But if I use,

```
Article.find({}, (err, title)
```

it works, but I do not need objects because they are all unique

I tried this link 
     [How do I query for distinct values in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043847/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose)

But it does not work for me.

For example, I have records:

One, Two, One

But need output: One, Two

Comment: Really hard to understand what you are looking for here, can you please add a sample input and your expected output?

Comment: I've given an example

Comment: Still as clear as mud. Are you expecting an array of documents e.g `[{ _id: 'xxxx', title: 'One' }, { _id: 'yyy', title: 'Two' }]` or just an array of strings i.e. titles `['One', 'Two']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `distinct` operator with the desired property (here, title) passed as parameter like this,

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Article.distinct('title', function(error, titles) { //see the use of distinct
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(articles);
      res.render('index', {
         title: 'Articles',
         articles: titles
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The following query will return an array of `title`, all distinct.

Hope this resolves the issue.