# Mongoose Query to Find Unique Values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB backend I want to create an endpoint that returns all the unique values for a property called `department`. Now, if I were doing this in IntelliShell I would just do something like:

```
db.staffmembers.distinct( "department" )
```

This will return an array of all the values for `department`.

But how do you return all unique values within a Mongoose find() query like this one?

```
Staffmember.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }});
```

In other words, what would the syntax look like if I want to use a `find()` like above, to return all unique values for `department` within the "staffmembers" collection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query for distinct values in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043847/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose)

Comment: Well distinct query also accepts filter argument. `db.staffmembers.distinct({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }}, "department")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `.aggregate()` and pass your condition into `$match` stage and then use `$addToSet` within `$group` to get unique values.

```
let result = await Staffmember.aggregate([
    { $match: { name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }} },
    { $group: { _id: null, departments: { $addToSet: "$department" } } }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use find and distinct like this for the above scenario. Aggregate might be a little overkill. I have tried both the solutions below.

```
Staffmember.find({name: 'john', age: {$gte: 18}}).distinct('department', 
   function(error, departments) {
       // departments is an array of all unique department names
   }
);

Staffmember.distinct('department', {name:'john', age:{ $gte: 18 }},
   function(error, departments) {
       // departments is an array of all unique department names
   }
);
```

This link just nails it with all different possibilities:
[How do I query for distinct values in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043847/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose)