# how to distinct value... mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

how to make "userId" distinct here?
Error: field selection and slice cannot be used with distinct

```
Rooms.find({roomId: room.roomId}).select("userId").where({deleted:"false"}).sort({date:1}).limit(50).exec()
     .then(docs =>{...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query for distinct values in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043847/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose)

Comment: it's not duplicated ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it thnx for helping

```js
Rooms.aggregate([{$sort:{date:1}}, {$group:{ _id : "$userId"}},{$limit:100}], function(err, docs){
           if(err ){... }
           else{...}
```

Answer (score -2):

in this case I don't know why u want t distinct this values. but to answer your question, you can use this code to query distinct values

```
Rooms.find({roomId: room.roomId}).distinct('room_id').select("userId").where({deleted:"false"}).sort({date:1}).limit(50).exec()
     .then(docs =>{...
```