# Mongo and node js a query to return with no duplicates , distinct

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, distinct, keystonejs

How do we query in mongo where in the results would not have duplicates , I have tried using distinc but it does not seem to work.

## Query

```
keystone.list('Customer').model.find().sort('name').where('vin').in([vin]).exec(

function (err, results) {

    if (err || !results.length) {
        return next(err);
    }
    .....
```

Comment: You need to be clear first. Are duplicate documents completely same or only some fields are same?. If only a field is same, you can use .distinct(fieldName) to get distinct values. If they are completely similar, I dont think it proper to store duplicate docs in the db. Provide some sample docs.

Comment: Just a field is the same

Comment: can you provide sample below ?

Comment: I have tried using distinc it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
keystone.list('Customer').model.find().distinct('customer_id')
  .where('fieldName', 'fieldValue')
  .exec(function(err, result) {
    //array of _ids
  });
```

Then pass all the ids in a `$in` query to get all the records.

Comment: keystone.list('Customer').model.find().distinct('customer_id').where('vin').in([vin]).exec(function (err, results) {

Comment: I was referring to the unique id in his case. Please view the update

Comment: After filtering, it will give him only distinct docs.  Dont down vote unnessarily.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043847/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose

Comment: Please moderators, view this

Comment: @Mr. Rajiv Kumar Its the correct answer. I have invested my time and researched for this.