# Mongoose how to count unique days in a month?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

i am working on a problem where in my database there supposed to be multiple entries from day to day.
each entry includes a timestamp. the problem is im supposed to find how many days in each month a data has been entered.
ex: if a user sends a message every 2 days in may. my answer would be: "the user used the message function for 15 days in may".
now if the user sends 5 messages every 2 days in may. the answer would be still 15. im only counting the days the user has been using the app.

using this query:

```
model.find({ 
    date: {
        $gte: new Date(startOfMonth), 
        $lt: new Date(endOfMonth)
    }
})
```

i was able to find all data entries on a specific month.
the data may look like something like this:

```
 Date: dd/mm/yy        Message:
 1/5/2022              "Hello"
 1/5/2022              "World"
 1/5/2022              "!"
 5/5/2022              "Hello World!"
 8/5/2022              "Hello World!"
```

the desired answer would be 3 unique days in may.

How do i achieve this using mongodb? the simplest answer that come to mind is to use additional queries to group by unique days, but i have no idea how to do that using mongo provided i need to access the date.

Comment: sounds like `distinct` is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043847/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose

Comment: @GrafiCode so how would that look like on my part?

Comment: I don't really know mongoose, but you could try `model.find.distinct({ .......... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might solves your problem. it will return distinct messages.

```
Model.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": {
            "date": { 
                "$gte": new Date(startOfMonth), "$lt": new Date(endOfMonth)
            }
        }},
        { "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "year":  { "$year": "$date" },
                "month": { "$month": "$date" },
                "day":   { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }
            }
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {
        // do something with result

    }
);
```

Comment: im trying to distinct dates. i did try to replace "$Message" with "$date", and it almost worked for me. but now it identifies every day separately because the hours are not matched. i only need to access the days only, and thats where i stumble

Comment: can you send your model once and exact outpu you want?

Comment: that indeed did work! i almost brute forced my way out of this by pre save the schema and removing hours/mins/sec from the data haha. BRAVO!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **distinct**
`db.collection.distinct({date:{$gte:new Date(startOfMonth),$lt:new Date(endOfMonth)}}).length`
if you are directly storing the date of it.

Note : This may not work if you're storing complete timestamp instead of date.

Comment: yes it's not working for me. although i've set the type of date to "Date"

Comment: No, setting it to type Date will not work.

Comment: Because Date includes timestamp too...

Comment: Which method would be the most suitable in my case then?